# android webview click html link programatically

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

guys. I m trying developing a simple youtube mp3 download project. I m using webview. I m loading this link to my webview "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&h=5671e7d33d4eccb5b89ea8f54d9911d4&r=1387110278658.1527580295". Then I want to click programatically the "Download" link. I've tried many methods but didn't work. The code below which I inserted works on Chrome Console . But don't work in android app . Could you help me?

web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('dl_link').getElementsByTagName('a')[2].click();");

```
             web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
                        "l=document.getElementById('dl_link').getElementsByTagName('a')[2];"+
                        "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
                        "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
                        "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
                        "})()");
```

Comment: Yes I found the solution.And I finished my application.What is your  problem?I did click event like this ;web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('example')[0].click();");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already I had made Webview.getSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

And I found solution;

Button Click event must be like this

web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('example')[0].click();"‌​);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you javascript enabled on your webview:

`Webview.getSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`